# How to set Nuxt.js' config for axios baseURL to work globally?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Created a project via

```
npm init nuxt-app <project-name>
```

Config `baseURL` for axios by [here](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup)

```
npm install @nuxtjs/axios
```

nuxt.config.js

```
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:9000',
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      browserBaseURL: process.env.BROWSER_BASE_URL
    }
  },

  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
    }
  },
```

Use it in pages/post.vue

```
axios.get('/posts')
```

Can't call server in `9000`, but got base URL as `3000` which port nuxt.js is running.

If config `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:9000'` in `pages/post.vue`, it can access correctly.

Comment: Same here. anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are accessing the "global" instance of `axios`, in order to use the instance provided/configured by `@nuxtjs/axios`, use `this.$axios.get('/posts')` in your Vue component.

Check more details here: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage

===============================

UPDATE

To add basic auth with your request, you can extend the `$axios` instance with nuxt plugin (some details here [Extending Axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend/) and here [Nuxt Plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins)).

Inside your plugin, add the authorization header in `onRequest` callback:

```js
export default ({ $axios }) => {
  $axios.onRequest(config => {
    config.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic {your base64 encoded username/password here}'
  })
}
```

Although it's not recommended to put your login credential directly in the source code, using environment variables would be more appropriate, but that's another topic, you can check here https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-env/ if you are interested.

In terms of CORS error, it basically means the browser does not allow JavaScript to communicate with a remote server with different domain/port/schema (origin), unless the remote server responds with a matching origin in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. A simple fix would be adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in your server response if you have control of the server, but you can search it for some more details, there are different solutions to this issue and may fit better with your specific circumstance.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, do you know how to set global basic auth for calling remote server which using `username` and `password` to protect the request? I set `auth: {username: 'username',password: 'password'},` in `axios { ... }` block of `nuxt.config.js`, but caused `CORS error` and `401 Unauthorized`. In other way I can access the server data via basic auth.

Comment: @realworld why don't you leverage the https://auth.nuxtjs.org/ that's already built in? it has everything you need, without you need to do all manually and maybe things that you might forget in your implementation...

Comment: @balexandre How to use it with basic auth? I didn't find its usage [here](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth/).

Comment: @realworld you can extend the $axios instance with nuxt plugin (some details here: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend/ and here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/), then inside your plugin, you can add the authorization header in onRequest callback:

`
export default ({ $axios }) => {
  $axios.onRequest(config => {
    config.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic {your base64 encoded username/password here}'
  })
}
`

Comment: @Lin Okay, thank you very much for your kindly help!

Comment: @realworld no worries, I add some more details in my answer because the comment is very limiting in markdown styles.

Answer (score 1):

To access global, you need to use this.$axios and you don't need to import it somewhere else.